# What are the differences between spark version [2.4.0] and [2.4.0.cloudera2]

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I looked for the spark dependencies on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/), there are many versions of the spark core, in `Central` and `Cloudera`, Central has version `2.4.0` and Cloudera version `2.4.0.Clouder1` or `2.4.0.Clouder2`

For example, in spark core dependencies, `RoaringBitmap` is version `0.5.11` in Central and `0.7.45` in Cloudera

If my pom dependencies are using the Central version I need to run it on a version of spark `2.4.0.cloudera`.
What can I need to do?

Comment: The difference is that the `Cloudera2` is another build of Spark done by **Cloudera**, in general they should be the _"same"_, but they do have small differences. If you are only going to deploy your app on a cloudera cluster, I would compile to the most specific version that you can.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez If my app dependencies on RoaringBitmap [0.7.45], but the production environment's spark is 2.4.0.cloudera1 and RoaringBitmap is [0.5.11], how do I compile it?

Comment: if **Spark** does not expose any class for that library. You can _shade_ your own version inside your path. That is a complex task, which I can not help with. I would suggest reading more about that, and if you have further problems, ask a new _(more specific)_ question. - Other option would be to use the same version that your Spark uses, which may be easier from the jar packaging, but would require code changes. _(note that if Spark exposes those classes, you can only go with this alternative, as shading will not work)_.